# Need help for recording semi acoustic guitar

Tags: homerecording

I have a semi acoustic guitar and I want to record some tunes that I have created. I don't have an amp so I think I can record by..maybe plugging the aux in the mic jack of - Quantum USB Sound Card QHM-623 for All Computer/PC https://www.amazon.in/dp/B007Z9K45U/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_taa_rKUgDbH6D0JS5
Is that possible..if not please suggest some cheap option. Cheers.

Comment: You need an interface with a dedicated guitar signal (Hi-Z) input, not a microphone input. Google "USB guitar interface".

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a computer with an auxiliary input, I cannot imagine that buying a 90 rupee (€1.15) USB audio interface will give you any benefit. In fact I think the converters on that USB device would only be enough for simple tasks such as voice calls. That being said, if all you want to do is record some tunes, then perhaps it is enough.

If I were you, I would invest in a small but good quality external USB audio interface. There are some decent ones under €100 (7,700 rupees?) that will provide a decent sound. See this link: https://www.pmtonline.co.uk/blog/2018/11/14/9-best-cheap-audio-interfaces-that-dont-suck/

Answer (score 1):

You guitar will have an 6.33mm jack. The USB Soundcard that you have postet has an 3.5mm jack. Maybe you can try to use an adapter from 6.3mm to 3.5mm so you can connect your guitar to the USB Soundcard. But i dont know if this will end in a horrible soundqualitiy.

Usuallay you would use an audiointerface. Its like an external soundcard for your computer (just like the Quantum USB Soundcard from you link, but made for recording). There are some models for beginners which aren't to expensive. You can connect your 6.3mm jack to the audio-interface and connect your audiointerface via usb to your pc. Most of the time there is an DAW (A programm for your pc which you use to record songs like Cubase, ProTool etc.) included if you buy a audio-interface.

You can visist [this site](https://www.thomann.de/gb/index.html?ref=intl&shp=eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoiZ2IiLCJjdXJyZW5jeSI6IjIiLCJsYW5ndWFnZSI6ImVuIn0%3D)

There you can contact the customer support. They are very friendly and if you tell them what you want to do, they will give you competent advise.